# XNA Deferred Shading, Replace BasicEffect

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, xna-content-pipeline, deferred-rendering

I have implemented deferred shading in my XNA 4.0 project, meaning that I need all objects to start out with the same shader "*RenderGBuffer.fx*". How can I use a custom Content Processor to:

1. Not load any textures by default (I want to manually do this)
2. Use "*RenderGBuffer.fx*" as the default shader instead of BasicEffect

Below is the progress so far

```
   public class DeferredModelProcessor : ModelProcessor
    {
       EffectMaterialContent deferredShader;

       public DeferredModelProcessor()
       {

       }

       protected override MaterialContent ConvertMaterial(MaterialContent material, ContentProcessorContext context)
       {
           deferredShader = new EffectMaterialContent();
           deferredShader.Effect = new ExternalReference<EffectContent>("DeferredShading/RenderGBuffer.fx");         

           return context.Convert<MaterialContent, MaterialContent>(deferredShader, typeof(MaterialProcessor).Name);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of a lot research, this is how you do it:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Processors;

namespace Deferred_Pipeline
{
    [ContentProcessor(DisplayName = "Deferred Model - Archon")]
    public class DeferredModelProcessor : ModelProcessor
    {
        public DeferredModelProcessor()
        {

        }

        protected override MaterialContent ConvertMaterial(MaterialContent material, ContentProcessorContext context)
        {
            EffectMaterialContent deferredShader = new EffectMaterialContent();
            deferredShader.Effect = new ExternalReference<EffectContent>("../ArchonContent/DeferredShading/RenderGBuffer.fx");            

            OpaqueDataDictionary processorParameters = new OpaqueDataDictionary();
            processorParameters["ColorKeyColor"] = this.ColorKeyColor;
            processorParameters["ColorKeyEnabled"] = this.ColorKeyEnabled;
            processorParameters["TextureFormat"] = this.TextureFormat;
            processorParameters["GenerateMipmaps"] = this.GenerateMipmaps;
            processorParameters["ResizeTexturesToPowerOfTwo"] = this.ResizeTexturesToPowerOfTwo;

            return context.Convert<MaterialContent, MaterialContent>(deferredShader, typeof(MaterialProcessor).Name, processorParameters);
        }
    }
}
```